# Como remover o public da url

Tags: php, htaccess, servidor

To criando uma pequena aplicação e tenho uma url do tipo **raiz/public/index.php**,
queria saber como remover esse public e deixar o a url só **raiz/index.php** usando o .htaccess. já procurei no Google e só achei exemplos relacionados a laravel e nenhum funcionou.

Comment: Lucas, você quem criou a pasta public?

Comment: Sim, eu que criei a pasta public

Comment: Geralmente o que fica na pasta public é o que é exposto na internet. Então o seu webserver serve apenas a public, você esta rodando onde a aplicação? Apache, IIS.. ?

Comment: To usando o apache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você está correto sobre o **.htaccess** ; pois é ele quem controla a distribuição e nomenclaturas de diretórios do apache, servidor que vai compilar seu php.

Para reescrever urls, você precisa usar o módulo rewrite do htaccess, dessa forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On      
## diretrizes      
  </IfModule>
```

Em seu exemplo, especificamente, vocÊ quer mudar uma única URL, no caso, ficaria assim:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^raiz/public/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ /raiz/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^raiz/public/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/$ /raiz/$1 [NC,L]
      </IfModule>
```

De forma resumida, tudo que for adicionado no terceiro nível do raiz/public será passado para "/raiz/TERCEIRO_NIVEL, no código, a variável $1

Ok? Espero ter ajudado e é importante saber que o .htaccess é muito importante para gerar URLs mais amigáveis, além de solucionar problemas como esse.

Lembre que as diretrizes alteram os caminhos de forma geral, então, talvez você vai precisar usar o caminho absoluto para gerar links de  ou  como exemplo.

Vou adicionar um .htaccess que uso muito nas minhas web apps, espero ajudar

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
   ##sempre utilizar https
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
  ## URL amigáveis enviando tudo para "site/site.php e diretórios como variaveis link
   RewriteRule ^$ site/site.php [L]

   RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ /site/site.php?link=$1 [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /site/site.php?link=$1 [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /site/site.php?link=$1&link2=$2 [NC,L]  

   RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /site/site.php?link=$1&link2=$2&link3=$3 [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /site/site.php?link=$1&link2=$2&link3=$3&link4=$4 [NC,L]

  </IfModule>   
## expirar o cache ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
##  ##  
#compactando arquivos
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
# BEGIN Caching
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Caching
```

Abs

Comment: Eu usei o seu código e acabou por não funcionar, mais graças a ele achei um codigo bem parecido com ele que funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Baseado na resposta do Leonardo, achei o código abaixo que resolve o problema.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^raiz$ [NC,OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^raiz$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !raiz/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /raiz/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Obrigado Lukas, espero ter ajudado. Vou editar minha resposta com alguns "power ups" de .htaccess que tem ajudado na performance das minhas web apps. Abs

Comment: Obg pela ajuda, vou testar esse htaccess